# NPM stuck on an old version?

Tags: node.js, npm

I was following some tutorial that was recorded a while ago, and it said for us to downgrade our npm version to 5.5.1 to avoid any differences (since that was the newest version at the time of the recording). So I did, using classic

```
npm install -g npm@5.5.1
```

However, now I'm stuck, I can't update to the actual present day latest version. I tried `npm install -g npm@latest`, I tried manually typing the latest version, I even tried uninstalling both Node and NPM, and installing the latest ones, fresh from the site, but for whatever reason my npm just gets stuck on 5.5.1 again. How do I fix this?

I'm using Windows btw. Also, I'm just learning about Node and NPM, so I guess there is a chance I'm missing some obvious solution?

Edit: whenever I try to install something, I get the following

> ```
> npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v12.18.3
> npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
> npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
> npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6,
>
> npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
> WARNING: You are likely using a version of node-tar or npm that is incompa
> with this version of Node.js.
> Please use either the version of npm that is bundled with Node.js, or a ve
> of npm (> 5.5.1 or < 5.4.0) or node-tar (> 4.0.1) that is compatible with
> s 9 and above.
> ```

and after that a long list of errors, including, but not limited to

> 1: 000000013F8A5EBF napi_wrap+114095
> 2: 000000013F850B46 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+66998
> 3: 000000013F850EC1 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+67889
> 4: 000000013F78F187 RSA_meth_get_flags+85639
> 5: 000000014001AAE0 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+323456

Comment: Did you try `npm install -g npm@latest`?  Your said "I tried `npm install npm@latest` but that that doesn't include the `-g`.  It looks like you installed globally the first time.  Use the `-g` flag again.

Comment: yes I tried it globally, I just forgot to add it in the question (edited now). Either way, same result, doesn't work

Comment: What version of `node` are you using?  Like the error said, you have to also be using an up to date version of node to use `npm@latest`.

Comment: the issue was my version was actually "too new", I tried downgrading it first, but that didn't solve everything, in the end it turned out to be a thing of AppData, as @Jatin Mehrotra wrote below. Still, thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this
Run PowerShell as Administrator

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force 
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade 
npm-windows-upgrade
```

refer to this https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-windows-upgrade or their GitHub [repo](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade) for more help

if it doesn't help, try this

uninstall node `(Settings -> Add or remove programs)`, then navigate to `C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming` and delete the `npm and npm-cache folder and finally install node again (using the installer).`

Comment: tried it, but it won't install npm-windows-upgrade, it just throws the same thing it does for every other attempt of installation (I added it now in the post)

Comment: yeah, I just stumbled upon that myself just 10 seconds ago, works fine now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `-g`.  You said:

> I tried `npm install npm@latest`

but that that doesn't include the `-g`.  The `-g` is key because it causes `npm` to be installed globally (best rhyme).  See [Downloading and installing packages globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally).  Your first command includes it, but not the follow up.

Because of this, you probably install `npm` as a **local** dependency (which you probably didn't mean to do).  Check your `package.json` and see if there is any listing of `npm`.  If you aren't directly using runtime pieces of `npm`, remove that dependency and just install the specific version you want globally with `-g`.

Comment: I actually tried it globally, but apparently forgot to add it in the question, my mistake. Either way, still the same results

Answer (score -1):

In your project root directory, run the update command:

```
npm update
```

Comment: tried it, but it doesn't work, just like the other options I listed above

Comment: This does not work